# How to fill a DataTable with a List(Of t) or convert a List(Of t) to a DataTable?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, structure, generic-list

I have read many posts on this topic; among them and most recently [.NET - Convert Generic Collection to Data Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701223/net-convert-generic-collection-to-datatable). Unfortunately, all to no avail.

I have a generic collection of structures :

```
Private Structure MyStruct
Dim sState as String
Dim lValue as Long
Dim iLayer as Integer
End Structure

Dim LOStates As New List(Of MyStruct)
```

I need to fill a DataTable with this list of structures but have no idea how to go about doing this. I am using vb.net in Visual Studio 2008.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code you linked assumes the members are declared as properties.  You didn't declare properties.  You can make it work with Reflection:

```
Imports System.Reflection
...

      Public Shared Function ConvertToDataTable(Of T)(ByVal list As IList(Of T)) As DataTable
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim fields() As FieldInfo = GetType(T).GetFields()
        For Each field As FieldInfo In fields
          table.Columns.Add(field.Name, field.FieldType)
        Next
        For Each item As T In list
          Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
          For Each field As FieldInfo In fields
            row(field.Name) = field.GetValue(item)
          Next
          table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        Return table
      End Function
```

Comment: nobugz, thank you for such a prompt response! I added this function to my class, then passed it the list of structures (oTable = ConvertToDataTable(LOStates)) but no rows were retruned - the table count = 0 before being returned to where it was called from. I'm wondering if there's something else that I'm missing or doing incorrectly...

Comment: Debug it.  Do the for each loops loop?  Does the table have any columns?

Comment: It was in debug that I was able to determine that the table count = 0. The for each loops loop indeed. There are 3 coumns but 0 rows right before the return table statement is executed.

Comment: I noticed that as soon as I finished typing my last response so I included the add statement. BUT after adding the first row to the DataTable, it craps out citing a "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" befor going on to add any more rows to teh DataTable.

Comment: Sorry for being such a pain in the tail! I really appreciate your help and patience :)

Comment: Oh nvm, I effed up w/ the declarations! It's all good. You're the man nobugz!

Comment: @HansPassant `GetType(T).GetFields()` returns an empty set for me, I had to use `GetProperties` which doesn't return a type castable to `FieldInfo`. I'm using ADO Entity models.

Comment: How to pass the list to this function in vb.net

Comment: @SamSelikoff, snipped translated to GetProperties http://stackoverflow.com/a/24739862/842935

Answer (score 8):

I have same issue than @SamSelikoff, moved to GetProperties:

```
Public Shared Function ConvertToDataTable(Of t)(
                                                  ByVal list As IList(Of t)
                                               ) As DataTable
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    If Not list.Any Then
        'don't know schema ....
        Return table
    End If
    Dim fields() = list.First.GetType.GetProperties
    For Each field In fields
        table.Columns.Add(field.Name, field.PropertyType)
    Next
    For Each item In list
        Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
        For Each field In fields
            dim p = item.GetType.GetProperty(field.Name)
            row(field.Name) = p.GetValue(item, Nothing)
        Next
        table.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    Return table
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @Hans Passant function if anyone is dealing with nullable types:

```
For Each field As FieldInfo In fields
' Extra check for nullable
If field.FieldType.AssemblyQualifiedName.Contains("System.Nullable") Then
    ' Insert proper type
    If field.FieldType.AssemblyQualifiedName.Contains("System.DateTime") Then
       table.Columns.Add(field.Name, Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
    End If
Else
    table.Columns.Add(field.Name, field.FieldType)
End If
Next
```

Values:

```
For Each item As T In list
Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
For Each field As FieldInfo In fields
    ' Check if value is null
    If field.GetValue(item) is nothing Then
        Continue For
    End If
    row(field.Name) = field.GetValue(item)
Next
table.Rows.Add(row)
Next
```