# List (Of T) as DataGridView.DataSource makes sorting fail

Tags: vb.net, list, datagridview, datatable, datasource

I have read some threads about this "error" but I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property PhoneNumber As string
    Public Property Age As Integer

    Public sub New(ByVal Values As String())
        Me.Name = Values(0)
        Me.PhoneNumber = Values(1)
        Me.Age = Convert.ToInt32(Values(2))
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get my data from a semicolon separated file, and i create a list of Person objects by looping this file and split on semicolon. Like this

```
Dim PersonsList As New List(Of Person)
For Each line in textfile..........
    PersonsList.Add(New Person(line.Split(";")))
Next
```

When the list is complete, I tell my DataGridView that `DataSource` is `PersonsList`.

This works like a charm, but I'm not able to sort the columns.
I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805626/how-to-fill-a-datatable-with-a-listof-t-or-convert-a-listof-t-to-a-datatable) amongst many (where the class values are not properties, which mine are) and tried that converting function which did'nt really work in my case. The right amount of rows were created, but all of the columns were blank.

What am I missing?

Comment: [The other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24739862/2998271) in the post you linked shows how to deal with properties.. does it work for you?

Comment: Nope, i get the same error with this one. Blank rows.

Comment: For the love of god! I'm sorry for this post. When i switched back to using my original list as source again I got blank rows even with this. A restart of VS and that second answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a datatable as the data source, column sorting is automatically enabled and you can sort the data by any column:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.AddRange(
        {
            New DataColumn("Name"),
            New DataColumn("Phone"),
            New DataColumn("Age")
        })
    For Each s As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("textfile1.txt")
        Dim temprow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        temprow.ItemArray = s.Split(";"c)
        dt.Rows.Add(temprow)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```