# how to convert list to datatable

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET - Convert Generic Collection to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701223/net-convert-generic-collection-to-datatable)

hi,
i want to convert list datatype to datatype.
i wrote the function

```
static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (var info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));
            }
            foreach (var t in list)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (var info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
                {
                    row[info.Name] = info.GetValue(t, null);
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

but this is throwing exception "DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>"
how can we solve this or is there any other solution

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
// When building table
Type pt = info.PropertyType;
if(pt.IsGenericType && pt.GetGenericTypeDefinition()==typeof(Nullable<>))
    pt = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pt);
}
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, pt)); 

// When loading table
row[info.Name] = info.GetValue(t, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
```