# How to create an Crystal Report from a XML (XML is from a Web Service) in C#

Tags: c#, xml, crystal-reports, linq-to-xml, crystal-reports-2010

I want to know how can i create an crystal report from a XML (XML is from a Web Service), I read in some tutorials that it needs to locate the file and drag the fields in the report, but how about a XML from a Web Service?

Here is the code how I get the XML from a Web Service

```
  var doc = XDocument.Parse(trx.GetCardTrx("xxxxx", "xxxx", "xxx", "", dateTimePicker1.Text, dateTimePicker2.Text, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "FALSE", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
MessageBox.Show(doc.ToString());
```

So this code return this kind of values (`From MessageBox.Show(doc.ToString()`)

[image]

And here is the code for the selected values that should be in the report

```
var summary = from r in doc.Descendants("TrxDetailCard") 
                      select new 
                      {
                          Account_Type = r.Element("Account_Type_CH").Value,
                          Captured = r.Element("Captured").Value,
                          Trans_Type_ID = r.Element("Trans_Type_ID").Value,
                          Acct_Num_CH = r.Element("Acct_Num_CH").Value,
                          Tip_Amt_MN = r.Element("Tip_Amt_MN").Value,
                          Total_Amt_MN = r.Element("Total_Amt_MN").Value,
                          Date_DT = r.Element("Date_DT").Value,
                      };
```

And What I want to happen is that to create a report using Crystal Reports with this values, not all values. Selected values only. How can I possibly do this? Any ideas will be a big help Thank you :D

Comment: are you familiar with reading XMLDocument..? can you also state what the file path is of this .xml file so that I can give you a valid example..

Comment: @DJKRAZE ,There is no xml file, the result is from a function of a web service

Comment: what is the name of the Report that you are trying to create.. I will add it to my answer..

Comment: @DJKRAZE, TransReport :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has not been tested but can you try something like the following

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Parse(trx.GetCardTrx("xxxxx", "xxxx", "xxx", "", dateTimePicker1.Text, dateTimePicker2.Text, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "FALSE", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));

  var data = new DataSet();
  var context = new XmlParserContext(null, new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable()), null, XmlSpace.None);
  var reader = doc
  data.ReadXml(reader);

  var report = new ReportDocument();

  report.SetDataSource(data);
  this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource.ReportSource = report;
```

The Idea in theory should work but you can reference something similar from this link 
[XML-based Crystal Report not updating child objects on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504563/xml-based-crystal-report-not-updating-child-objects-on-refresh)

Comment: Why is there a path? Can I do it just something TransReport rpt = new TransReport(); rpt.SetDataSource(data); crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt; ??

Comment: there is error "Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' to 'System.Xml.XmlReader'
"

Comment: And I cannot call "crystalReportViewer1.ViewCore? I use only "crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report; "

Comment: Here is a good link as well for xDocument to XmlReader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa

Comment: still got error "Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' to 'System.Xml.XmlReader'"

Comment: is there a way that you can save the xml to a directory then send me your code i'll fix it for you...

Comment: do I have to save to directory?